# Excel VBA: How to Solve: DDE stops when remote application disconnect?

Tags: excel, dde, vba

I have (.xlsm) file connecting through DDE linking to a prices provider's streaming application, now if the provider application disconnect (e.g. because of net disconnection), the DDE linking stops and even VBA scheduling to check last time my xlsm data update for updating through `ThisWorkbook.UpdateRemoteReferences = True` using `Application.OnTime` stops.

What's the best scenario for having DDE consistent linking as `Application.OnTime` stops permanently if the remote provider updating stops temporarily !

The best approach and the ideal is to have the dde working as soon as the provider's application server reconnect but 
I don't now if there is a way for that?

The reference set using cells assignment `=ProviderServer|section!field`

================

## Edit to add a small OnTime testing function that stops for any vba error that I don't know

```
Function TimingTest()
        Cells(4, 2).Value = Time
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "TimingTest"
End Function
```

This function is in the separate (No Links) xlsm file but still stops after a period and no err.no I could get. I could get the last time it fired but I can't react as OnTime scheduling codes stops.

Comment: It sounds like your provider's streaming application is breaking the link, not Excel. Are you able to contact them and ask how it's supposed to be re-established?

Comment: I believe the provider team I could contact won't have the answer, I use

Comment: I use ThisWorkbook.UpdateRemoteReferences = True to update the links again and it works but the problem is that I need to do this (clicking::Firing) manually as the application.ontime breaks or stops scheduling even I tried using a separate instance xlsm file with no links at all just to schedule and check my 1st xlsm every minute but it also stops. Even I tested the scheduling (Application.Ontime) to show current time in a cell but it even stops after a period with no known reason. Maybe there is another function to test the dde connection like (SetLinkOnData) or (LinkSources) ??

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this question? If you have a problem with it, post a comment so that he can know how to ask a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Application.OnTime` isn't firing, it means that the function called by `Application.OnTime` is hung or crashed. My suggestion is that you write your own `Sub` and cause it to be called from `Application.OnTime` --- then you can use `On Error` to check for any crash, also you can log somewhere when the function exits successfully, this will show if it's hanging. Unfortunately I don't know a good way to interrupt it if it does hang.

Comment: Thanks brother for your support. Please check my editing. Maybe there is another approach we could get a consistent DDE connection!!

Comment: Thanks brother AnotherParker, you guided me to try to handle more error but eventually I need to keep the code continues. I have a lot of functions..is there away to set the st. On Error Resume Next for all workbook functions coz I found out it will work ideally only for the mother function that has the statement?! .. I apologize as they might downvoting the question because I asked about it at c++ room...(I like when programmers meet and live chat but I don't know how to find VBA room or windows room if there is.

Comment: No, there's no way to cause `On Error Resume Next` without adding it to all your functions yourself. Check out the Rubberduck project http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/ it may make it easier to make large changes to the code.

Comment: I've done it manually for all functions. Thank you for the link and every thing. I'll download it as soon I reach home. I think it would be very very useful . I really appreciate it..thanks.

Comment: I installed it and done the registry command successfully but unfortunately I still get the error message.